# How do you get a dead angler npc back to your base

Tags: terraria

So basically during the invasion my angler died because it was being pushed at the wall(I was on the other side of the wall) and until now I cant make him respawn I even tried going back to the ocean but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already rescued him and have a house available for him, he should spawn after a while. Make sure there's room for him to spawn.

If you haven't "saved" him, you need to go back to the ocean.